# Fortran error 5082

Tags: fortran, syntax-error

I'm very new at Fortran. I'm trying to compile this Fortran, I think 90??? Code. I'm using visual studio with the intel compiler.

The following code is giving me an error 5082. I have absolutely no idea why. Like literally no clue. Please, please help.

```
 integer function Dub(n) 
 integer n 
 Dub = 2*n 
 return    
 end


program Subroutines

implicit none

! Variables
integer n 
n = 5 


! Body of Subroutines
write(*,*) n 
Dub(n) 


write(*,*) 'Press Enter to Exit' 
read(*,*)
stop
end program Subroutines
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: You're not supposed to remember, you're supposed to paste it in.

Comment: Also you should tell us whose compiler and which version you are using, and show the compile command line - in addition to the complete and exact text of any diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran a call to a function, or a subroutine, must be part of a statement (or an initialization expression, but that's more advanced). `name(argument[s])` by itself is not a statement, unlike some other languages such as C, C++ and Java. A function call must be in an expression, and a subroutine call must use the `call` keyword. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions for examples.

Changing that line of your program to `n = Dub(n)` would make it legal, but rather useless. That function does nothing except return a value, and your main program does nothing useful with the value returned. Generally you call a function because you want either a side effect from executing the function, or to use the returned value, or both.

Comment: Probably wanted: `write (*,*) dub(n)`